# Why did the Chachamim cite Pirkei Avot 2:9 and not 4:1 in the dialogue with Alexander?

Tags: talmud-gemara, pirke-avot-ethicsof

In Pirkei Avot, Ben Zoma teaches us in Pirkei Avot 4:1 this oft-cited maxim,

> בֶּן זוֹמָא אוֹמֵר, אֵיזֶהוּ חָכָם, הַלּוֹמֵד מִכָּל אָדָם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (תהלים קיט) מִכָּל מְלַמְּדַי הִשְׂכַּלְתִּי כִּי עֵדְוֹתֶיךָ שִׂיחָה לִּי
>
> Ben Zoma said:Who is wise? He who learns from every man, as it is said: “From all who taught me have I gained understanding”

However, if one finds himself in Masechet Tamid (32a), he is met with the incident of Alexander the Great - when he approached and asked of the Chachamim for the definition of a Chacham.

> אמר להם אידין מתקרי חכים אמרו ליה איזהו חכם הרואה את הנולד
>
> Alexander said to the Elders: **Who is truly worthy of being called wise? They said to him,** citing a tradition (see Avot 2:9): **Who is the wise person? The one who sees and anticipates the consequences of his behavior.**

They cited the mishnah found in [Pirkei Avot 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.9?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). The Mishnah there asks for the correct "path" one should take.

> אָמַר לָהֶם, צְאוּ וּרְאוּ אֵיזוֹהִי דֶרֶךְ יְשָׁרָה שֶׁיִּדְבַּק בָּהּ הָאָדָם...רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן אוֹמֵר, הָרוֹאֶה אֶת הַנּוֹלָד.
>
> He [Rabban Yohanan] said unto them: go forth and observe which is the right way to which a man should cleave?...; Rabbi Shimon said, foresight.

I ask

a.) Why did the Chachamim choose the definition from Pirkei Avot 2:9 as opposed to 4:1?

b.) The Mishnah in 2:9 teaches how one should conduct himself  - אֵיזוֹהִי דֶרֶךְ יְשָׁרָה שֶׁיִּדְבַּק בָּהּ הָאָדָם, it did not specify what constitutes a Chacham. How did the Chachamim understand it as the latter?

Note: I am aware when I use "definition" for "The definition of a Chacham, it's not it's actual definition, rather a chief characteristic of a Chacham.

Answer (score 3):

The Chidushei Agados (Maharsha) asks and answers this question. See below my attempt to mark in bold the parts most relevant to your question, as well as my attempt at translating the bolded portions.

> **א״ל איזהו חכם הרואה את הנולד** כו׳ ואיזהו גבור כו׳. בפ״ד דאבות קאמר גבי גבור ועשיר כי הכא **אבל בחכם קאמר בע״א איזהו חכם הלומד מכל אדם והך
> דרואה את הנולד קא״ל** בפ״ב דאבות גבי איזה דרך שידבק בה אדם **ונראה
> דאלו השאלות כלפי עצמו שאלם שישבחו ויהללו אותו בהן לפי שהיה חכם בחכמת
> הפיליסופיא** שהיה תלמידו של אריסטוטלוס והיה גבור כובש כמה ארצות וגם
> עושר בנכסים שאסף במלחמה **אבל הם השיבו לו ע״פ מ״ש הכתוב אל יתהלל חכם
> בחכמתו** גו׳ כי אם בזאת יתהלל המתהלל השכל גו׳ דהוא תכלית ואושר האמיתי
> וז״ש לו **כששאלן שישבחו אותו בחכמתו הפילוסופיא א״ל דאין זה חכם אמיתי
> אבל הרואה את הנולד שהוא מביט ורואה לתכלית שהוא נולד לבסוף דהיינו וידוע
> אותי הוא החכם האמיתי** ואח״כ שאלן איזו גבור שישבחו אותו על שכבש כמה
> ארצות והשיבו לו שאין זה גבורה אמיתית אלא כובש את יצרו כדמייתי לה מקרא
> בפ״ג דאבות וכן קא״ל איזהו עשיר כו׳ שישבחו אותו בעושר וא״ל שאין זה עושר
> אמיתי הבא לו בגזילה במלחמה אבל זה השמח בחלקו ונהנה מיגיע כפו כדמייתי
> לה מקרא שם זהו עושר האמיתי:
>
> He said to them, "*who is wise?*" and they replied "*haroeh es hanolad
> (he who anticipates the future)*". But in Pirkei Avos they say "*who
> is wise? halomed mikol adam (he who learns from everyone)*", while
> here they say "*haroeh es hanolad*". And we can see that these
> questions that Alexander asked were asked in such a way that they
> should praise him, as he was *chacham* (wise) in the chochma of
> philosophy, but they replied to him in a different way, as it says [in
> Yirmiyahu] "*al yis'halel chochom bechochmaso (let not the wise man
> glory in his wisdom)*". So when he asked them so that they should
> praise him for his wisdom in philosophy, they replied to him that this
> is not true wisdom, but rather someone who is *roeh es hanolad*, who
> sees what the ultimate outcome of events will be; he is a true wise
> man.

Comment: I had the same in mind but could not find it unfortunately. Thanks and great job! See also the commentary of the Mefaresh on Tamid 32a and the אמרי יעקב - אבות on page 131: https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/180630/p/131/t/0.8597273340915391234/fs/kU1zBS8zdyc0T31jw4NetxjzSgtTwn02hVzpwZoNxPtj/start/282/end/285/c

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. Does anyone address the second part of my question?